# Google Spreadsheet : sort greatest values from a sort/uniq/sumifs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use Google Spreadsheet to keep track of my wine cellar, with a simple sheet with *number of bottles / name of the wine / where it's from* :

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+
| # of bottles |    Wine    | Appellation |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
|            2 | Talbot     | St Julien   |
|           16 | Marbuzet   | St Estephe  |
|            1 | Terrebrune | Bandol      |
|           10 | Madiniere  | Cote Rotie  |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

I'd like to get a roundup of appellation I have the most, sorted by number of bottles, eg:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| # of bottles | Appellation |
+--------------+-------------+
|           16 | St Estephe  |
|           10 | Cote Rotie  |
|          ... | ...         |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I know how to get the sorted list of appellations (`=sort(UNIQUE($C$2:$C$999)` with wine origin in column C) and the matching number of bottles (`=SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,<cell with appellation name>)`, but I'm stuck at sorting by the number of bottles instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `QUERY`

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select sum(A),C group by C order by sum(A) desc",1)
```

To rename the header:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select sum(A),C group by C order by sum(A) desc label sum(A) '# of bottles'",1)
```

---

With `SORT` and `SUMIF`

```
=ArrayFormula(SORT({SUMIF(C:C,UNIQUE(C2:C),A:A),UNIQUE(C2:C)},1,FALSE))
```